# Debug apk is working fine. However, the signed APK is not working properly

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-authentication, android-developer-api

I am facing a problem in the last part of my development of the Android app. I had to make an app in which online video stream from and database and also also a authentication is there which is done by mobile number using firebase and my problem is that the debug app is working properly but the signed apk is not working properly at authentication section it does not send verification code please help me out configure it..

Answer (score 1):

I have faced these kinds of issues because of proguard rules. Please check if signed apk working without proguard

Comment: Proguard just obfuscate your code. It is used so that if someone gets app of your app and decompile it then he/she might not be able to understand the code properly. I was facing problem because I was using GSON library to deserialise the response coming from backend API. As GSON uses reflection, it looks for the names mentioned in the Pojo file. But because of proguard field names in the Pojo were obfuscated and data was not deserialised.
If you are also doing similar things then you should check your proguard files

Comment: NO, I am not using that my code is simple and there is not GSON and other extra stuff but thanks for helping buddy I will check more documentaio

Comment: Thanks Rahul, Same Pojo class Issue here from 2 days..Solved it today with using your comment.. I have added this     -keep class xxx.packagename.classname { *; } inside proguard and issue is solved..